# Optional Parameter on Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router

So I have a project Page and when I click in one project I want to go to Project Detail page of that project. so I'm using dynamic routes. I pass as parameters a name(that will show on URL) and Id(that I use to go to my store and get the project, this Id is not showing on URL). Everything is ok, the problem is when I Load the browserinside the project Detail page, I only get name as a parameter and I cant get the Id so because of that I cant match the Id with my vuex because there is no Id.

this is my router-link on parent

```
<router-link class="project__icon" :project="project" :to="{ name: 'projectDetail', params: {name: project.name.replace(' ', ''), id: project.id} }">
```

and this is what I do on other page to get my project Id inside Vuex

```
const projectId = this.$route.params.id; 
    this.project = this.$store.getters.getProject(projectId);
```

This is what I get when I click on router

```
http://localhost:8080/project/myprojectName
```

On my router file I have this

```
{
 path: '/project/:name',
 name: 'projectDetail',
 component: ProjectDetail,
},
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you are binding `project` to the `router-link`, shouldn't be necessary.

```
<router-link class="project__icon" :to="{ name: 'projectDetail', params: {name: project.name.replace(' ', ''), id: project.id} }">
```

You need to add `:id` as a parameter to your route.  You can mark it optional with a `?`.

```
{
 path: '/project/:name/:id?',
 name: 'projectDetail',
 component: ProjectDetail,
}
```

Also, if you set `props: true` you can decouple your component from the router and instead of using `this.$route.params.id`, your detail component will receive the parameters as props.

```
{
 path: '/project/:name/:id?',
 name: 'projectDetail',
 component: ProjectDetail,
 props: true,
}
```

EDIT:  You have to have the id in the url if you want to allow refreshing and still keep the id or you have to store it somewhere like `localstorage` or `sessionstorage`.

Comment: Actually it works but I'll get the id everytime I click on router. 

```
localhost:8080/project/myprojectName/0 

```

Actually I found the solution, without knowing why, It's pretty easy, I just need to

```

 this.project.id

```
 Still dont know how this works because I'm refreashing the page inside the component, but component itself already know the project. Thanks for your hel